# Show/Hide div by specific text of data bound dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm new to programming.

I have a databound dropdownlist to a 2013 access db of a list of countries.
I want to show/hide a division where there is a different textbox (where you fill your date of immigration) depending on your chosen country.

Example:

If you chose UK as country of birth, the text box for date of immigration will show. But if you chose US as country of birth, the text box for date of immigration will not show.

I thought to use jquery, but it's not working.
How do I get the value of the chosen index of the dropdownlist?

Code:

```
jquery:
$("#birthcountrylist").change(function)
{
if($(this).val()=="US") { $(divimmigratedate).hide(); }
else { $(divimmigratedate).show(); }
}); 

form:
<!-- Entering Birth Country /-->
<asp:DropDownList ID="birthcountrylist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"></asp:DropDownList

<!--Entering Date of Immigration/-->
<div id="divimmigratedate" runat="server" style="display:none">
<asp:TextBox ID="dateimmigrate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="13%" Text="" ></asp:TextBox>

back-code:
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            OleDbConnection db = new OleDbConnection("");
            db.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=countriesdb.accdb;"].ToString();
            db.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Countries FROM countryofbirth";
            cmd.Connection = db;
            OleDbCommand dbc = new OleDbCommand(cmd.CommandText, db);
            OleDbDataReader read = dbc.ExecuteReader();

            birthcountrylist.DataSource = read;
            birthcountrylist.DataTextField = "Countries";       
            birthcountrylist.DataValueField = "Countries";
            birthcountrylist.DataBind();
            read.Close();
            db.Close();
        }
    }
```

I think my problem is with this part:

```
if($(this).val()=="US")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a syntax error for [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function.

jquery:

```
$("#birthcountrylist").change(function()
{
if($(this).val()=="US") { $(divimmigratedate).hide(); }
else { $(divimmigratedate).show(); }
});
```

Comment: Didn't notice the rackets,though it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

check the following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#birthcountrylist').change(function () {
            if ($('#<%=birthcountrylist.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == "US") {
                alert("hello world1");
            }
            else {
                alert("hello world2");
            }
        })
    });       
</script>
```

And here goes the HTML portion

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="birthcountrylist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="hello world 1" Value="US"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="hello world 2" Value="UK"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Let me know if it works , thanks ..